# How to map domain in AWS Route53 with GCP Cloud Run app

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, google-cloud-run

Our domain is registered in Route 53. We have 1 hosted zone, and the domain is currently used for one of our EC2 instances (I think as an elastic IP address). Our hosted zone has all of the records needed to work with our EC2 instance. We now need to use this domain instead for my an application deployed through GCP's Cloud Run. I have headed to `console.cloud.google.com/run/domains` and clicked **Add Mapping**, typed in our base url, and received a button to **Verify in Webmaster Central**, which I click, bringing me to this google page with this dropdown (in the images below I changed my url to the fake domain `mydomain.com`):

[image]

This dropdown does not have `Route53` or `Amazon Registrar` as an option, and I'm not sure what other option to choose. At the bottom is **Other**, which opens up the following menu:

[image]

For step 1, I am struggling. I have logged into my AWS account, went to Route 53, and created a new hosted zone for `mydomain.com`:

[image]

I click on the new hosted zone for `mydomain.com`, click **create record**, choose **Simple Routing** for the policy (there were 6 options: Simple Routing, Weighted, Geolocation, Latency, Failover, Multivalue answer), then click Define Simple Record, and get sent to this page:

[image]

I left the record name blank, set the Record Type to TXT, selected **IP address or another value depending on the record type**, and copy/pasted the line from the google webmaster verification page into the input field. They I click **Define Simple Record** to create the record.

Unfortunately, after all of this, the verification is not successful from the Google Webmaster verification page. To confirm this, I am receiving the following error notification when I click **Verify**:

[image]

Perhaps moving the domain from Route 53 to Google's DNS would be easier, although to me it seems simpler to leave the domain in AWS and simply give permission to the Cloud Run app to use the domain. This seems like it would be an issue for anybody with an app in Cloud Run and a domain in AWS Route 53.

### Edit

When I run `dig TXT mydomain.com` from the command line, I get something that looks like this (numbers edited):

```
MyComputer-1:Documents myname$ dig TXT mydomain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> TXT mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26912
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cbbanalytics.com.              IN      TXT

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mydomain.com.       900     IN      SOA     ns-923.awsdns-18.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 5740 300 1204600 86210

;; Query time: 87 msec
;; SERVER: 6300:1004:dc40:4b00::1#53(2600:1400:dc40:4b00::1)
;; WHEN: Thu Sep 24 11:14:11 PDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 123

Nicholass-MBP-5:Documents nicholas$
```

Comment: Why `TXT`? Why not CNAME?

Comment: @Marcin why the `CNAME` over the `TXT`? (i don't know anything about these things). Makes sense though to give it a try, so I will

Comment: You said "We have 1 hosted zone", but then you said "I created a new hosted zone". Do you now have 2 zones for the same domain?

Comment: @DusanBajic yes I do have 2. the first hosted zone is the original one used (still currently) with the EC2 instance. the second hosted zone is the one i just created. the 4th screenshot shows this as there are two hosted zones for `mydomain.com`.

Comment: Only one can be valid, and in your case it is most probably the first one. Create TXT record within the first zone.

Comment: @DusanBajic trying now. Do you think I am right to select `IP address or another value depending on the record type`, and they copy/paste `google-site-verification=ABCDE1234...` into the value field as such? Am I creating the TXT record correctly here?

Comment: looks like it worked

Answer (score 2):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer section)*.

Per suggestion in the comments, I deleted the 2nd hosted zone, created the TXT record in the 1st hosted zone (in the same way as done in the screenshot above), and the verification worked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

DNS records can take time to propagate, the best would be to query your domain like:

```
dig TXT mydomain.com
```

If this doesn't work, it's not Google's fault –you might be misconfiguring your nameservers on the domain name incorrectly (they might not even be pointing to Route53).

If `dig` returns the desired answer, check the Verification screen again and try verifying again.

Comment: Thanks @AhmetB - I went ahead and edited my question with the output from `dig TXT mydomain.com`. This looks good? However I tried again this morning to Verify on Google and received the same `We weren't able to verify your property: mydomain.com` from the Webmaster Central page.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was also necessary to add a CNAME registry in Route 53 with the prefix used on Cloud Run.

Name: myprefix.mydomain.com
Value: ghs.googlehosted.com.

You can find this, on GCP, by clicking Actions (three vertical dots) on the line of your domain, on mapped domains, in Cloud Run.